# Where can I find a list of all the PHP functions?

Tags: php

Is there a place I can find a list of all the php functions with an explanation of what the function does?

Comment: Download php manual for offline reading from here http://in.php.net/get/php_manual_en.chm/from/a/mirror

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/indexes.functions.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/docs.php), specifically the [Function and Method listing](http://php.net/manual/en/indexes.functions.php) page has a list of all the functions.

Comment: Do you think that such a list would be enough to write a decent auto-completion feature for a PHP IDE ? It seems that not too many PHP IDEs do that and I always wondered why.

Comment: @P.R. Sure, it's a complete list of the functions and their descriptions, so certainly enough to write an autocomplete feature. Although I would've thought most PHP IDEs would already have this.

Comment: No longer exists. Redirects to `search.php`.

Comment: @RichAdams Wow, thanks! I'd been looking but couldn't find that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find really anything you want on [php.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/).
You can also download it.